# JavaScript how to find unique values in an array based on values in a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I have a nested/multi-dimensional array like so:

[ [ **1**, 1, a ], [ **1**, 1 , b ], [ **2**, 2, c ], [ **1** ,1, d ] ]

And I want to filter it so that it returns only unique values of the outer array based on the ***1st*** value of each nested array.

So from the above array, it would return:

```
[ [1,1,a] [2,2,c] ]
```

Am trying to do this in vanilla javascript if possible. Thanks for any input! =)

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
const dedup = arr.filter((item, idx) => arr.findIndex(x => x[0] == item[0]) == idx)
```

It looks simple and also somehow tricky a bit.

Comment: this code was written ES5. would work for all browsers.

Comment: Note that this solution is O(n^2) and therefore not ideal if `arr` is large.

Answer (score 1):

I realize there's already three solutions, but I don't like them. My solution is

1. Generic - you can use unique with any selector function
2. O(n) - it uses a set, it doesn't run in O(n^2) time

So here it is:

```js
/**
 * @param arr - The array to get the unique values of
 * @param uniqueBy - Takes the value and selects a criterion by which unique values should be taken
 * 
 * @returns A new array containing the original values
 * 
 * @example unique(["hello", "hElLo", "friend"], s => s.toLowerCase()) // ["hello", "friend"]
 */
function unique(arr, uniqueBy) {
    const temp = new Set()
    return arr.filter(v => {
        const computed = uniqueBy(v)
        const isContained = temp.has(computed)
        temp.add(computed)
        return !isContained
    })
}

const arr = [ [ 1, 1, 'a' ], [ 1, 1, 'b' ], [ 2, 2, 'c' ], [ 1, 1, 'd' ] ]

console.log(unique(arr, v => v[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter with a set and given index.

```js
const
    uniqueByIndex = (i, s = new Set) => array => !s.has(array[i]) && s.add(array[i]),
    data = [[1, 1, 'a'], [1, 1, 'b'], [2, 2, 'c'], [1, 1, 'd']],
    result = data.filter(uniqueByIndex(0));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [[1,1,'a'], [1,1,'b'], [2,2,'c'], [1,1,'d']]

const res = input.reduce((acc, e) => acc.find(x => x[0] === e[0])
                                                   ? acc
                                                   : [...acc, e], [])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

Create the object with keys as first element of array. Iterate over array, check if the first element of array exist in the Object, if not push into the array.

```js
const nestedArr = [ [1,1,"a"], [1,1,"b"], [2,2,"c"], [1,1,"d"] ];
const output = {};

for(let arr of nestedArr) {
    if(!output[arr[0]]) {
        output[arr[0]] = arr;
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(output));
```

Another solution, would be to maintain the count of first array element and if the count is equal to 1, then push in the final array.

```js
const input = [ [1,1,"a"], [1,1,"b"], [2,2,"c"], [1,1,"d"] ],
         count = {},
         output = [];
         
input.forEach(arr => {
    count[arr[0]] = (count[arr[0]] || 0) + 1;
    if(count[arr[0]] === 1)  {
        output.push(arr);
    }
})

console.log(output);
```